# cannot parse {{blog.content}} inside if condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I made a blog website and I am trying to render all my posts. I have truncated my posts whose content was greater than 500 alphabets and I added a read more anchor tag.
I want that read more anchor tag to come only if my content is greater than 500 works
I wrote this line but it didn't work:

```
   {% for blog in blogs %}
<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">

        <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">{{blog.author}}</strong>
        <h3 class="mb-0">
            <a class="text-dark" href="/blog/{{blog.slug}}">{{blog.title}}</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{blog.timeStamp}}</div>
        <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{blog.content | truncatechars:500 }}</p>
        {% if len({{blog.content) >500 %}
        <a href="/blog/{{blog.slug}}">Continue reading</a>
        {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

can someone help me with what I should use in place of this code?

Comment: You are using a `for` tag instead of an `if` tag. For tags are for looping over a list of elements instead of a condition.

Comment: i am sorry it was a typing mistake i have written if in my code

Comment: Can you show what the rest of you template looks like? And please include your `Post` model as well.

Comment: ok please recheck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    {% if blog.content|length > 500 %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your code, because in `{% if len({{blog.content) >500 %}` you do not close your `{{` bracket.

However, you don't have to reference variables with `{{ }}` inside a `{% %}` tag. They both have a separate purpose.

The correct code for your specific problem is:

```
{% if blog.content|length > 500 %}
    <a href="/blog/{{blog.slug}}">Continue reading</a>
{% endif %}
```

As for the different tags, one is used to include variables inside your template: `<body> {{variable_here}} </body>`

The other is for logic: `{% if condition == True %} <p> Condition is true </p> {% endif %}`

Inside a logic tag, you can reference variables as is.

There's more about this in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#variables).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
{% if blog.content|length > 500 %}
```

as I am not sure if len could be used in templates